# create automount entries

Tags: linux, solaris, automount

on a Linux or Solaris server, using automount/autofs, how do i create/populate a directory with automount entries without mounting them ?

For example, i have `/data yp:auto.data` and /data/ subdirectories are only created after the first access. This is not persistent across reboot on Linux.

Is there a way to populate my /data without mounting all the disks ? So that users/applications see /data/disk1..N even if they are not mounted.

Comment: I've just found BROWSE_MODE for RedHat http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-The_sysconfig_Directory.html it's poorly documented, i'm going to try it on monday.

Comment: Yep, BROWSE_MODE=yes seems to do the trick on RedHat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Solaris, that's the default mode, and you need to specify `-nobrowse` in automount maps to disable it.   (For instance, we have our source code workspaces browsable, but home directories under auto_home are not, since no one wants to wait for 30,000 subdirs to load when trying to save a file in their home directory using a GUI file selection dialog, especially not in GUI's that stat each one, causing a mount, just to determine whether to display a folder or file icon.)

For more details see the *Browsing* section of [the automount(1m) man page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/automount-1m.html) and the [autofs browsability sections of the System Administration Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E23823_01/html/816-4555/rfsadmin-127.html#rfsadmin-195).